# Controlling getchar() in while loop

Tags: c, getchar

Say I have a simple `while` loop to enter **1*0* characters.
After more than 10, I want the loop to stop. 
However, the `break` seems not to take effect. 
Only when I press `Enter` it ends. Can anyone explain please?

```js
int count = 0;
int numchars = 10;
ch = getchar();
while( ch != '\n' && ch != '\0' ) {     
    array[count] = ch;
    count++;    
    if ( count > numchars ){        
        break;          
    }
    ch = getchar(); 
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: put the last ch=getchar() before break.

Comment: Your problem is that the first character is not read until the enter/return key is hit. You have to tweak the controls on your terminal (probably from within your program) to get characters as they are typed by the user.

Comment: Using `setvbuf` to turn off buffering may or may not fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stdin is not your tty, even when your tty is connected to stdin. Unless you put your tty in raw mode, the program does not see any data at all until you hit return.  When you hit return, all of the data on the line is sent to the program, which then enters the loop and reads characters until it breaks out of the loop.  If you really want the program to see characters as you press them, you will need to do a lot more work.  Look into libraries like `ncurses` first, and then do some research on how to put a tty into raw mode.  And then write the simple program that requires the user to hit return.

Answer (score 0):

use `getch()` or `getche()` instead of `getchar()` and `numchars=9` for `10` characters.